InitelliJ and changing SpringBoot property location
I have created dedicated application-local.yml and bootstrap-local.yml to allow application to run locally on my computer. According to this article it should work out of the box when I will set IntelliJ active profile to local but what I can see is that application will use only application-local not bootstrap-local (will load default bootsrtap.yml file).
I tried to set it as env variable in the IntelliJ, but that is not working either.
Any clue what is going on?
Update:
pom.xml has
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>


The article describes about Spring Cloud. Make sure your application is Spring cloud project.

@AnhTuấnNguyễn I have updated OP. Should I specify spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap as well?

Adding it did not solved my problem

Hi @JackTheKnife, There is only bootsrtap.yml file that will be used, refer this post

@AnhTuấnNguyễn Interesting because an article mentioned in the OP states something opposite.
